# how to edit a footer of pdf template on dolibarr

Tags: templates, pdf, erp

I am using the erp/crm dolibarr 3.8.3 and I want to edit the footer of a pdf template. for that I duplicated a template(for example azure propals). with that I have two identical templates. I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php/Create_a_PDF_document_template).

The problem is that I don't know how to add text in the footer, and I don't know where I should add those php code lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all the documents have the same footer so doesn't need to edit the template but the file core\lib\pdf.lib. you can check for the function pdf_pagefoot that's where the footer is generated

Answer (score 2):

You can create your template pdf and define a new footer for it,

-so to create a new template you should copy and paste a basic dolibarr template 
in the same directory under core/modules.
-it will be visible under dolibarr invoice/proposal/order document management section
-you can enable and see it when generation pdf or invoice /proposal/order